# How can I make new fields available to the report designer?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I replaced old SP (sp_ReportMonthlySales) in the .rdl file with the new one:

```
<CommandText>
      set fmtonly off;
      exec sp_ReportMonthlySalesEnhanced @Cyear,@Cmonth</CommandText>
<rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
```

This new SP has four additional values that are being returned in the result set; the four "CU" values are new:

```
select CY.CSDirector, CY.Category, CY.Segment, CY._Unit, 
       CU.New, CU.Assumed, CU.Existing, CU.Organic, 
       CY.NumUnits, CY.NumUnitsLast, CY.MonthSales, CY.MonthSalesLast, 
       CY.MonthPerc, CY.YTDSales, CY.YTDSalesLast, CY.YTDPerc,
       CY.ProjSales, CY.YTDProjSales, CY.YTDBudgetPerc, CY.NewBiz 
from #CombinedYears CY
left join #CategorizedUnits CU on CU.Unit = CY._Unit
```

IOW, these are new:

```
CU.New, CU.Assumed, CU.Existing, CU.Organic,
```

But they are not available when I try to assign the field to the corresponding slot on the design surface:

[image]

How do I make those fields available for choosing? What sort of refresh or manual adding do I need to do?

### UPDATE

I don't see where the "Dataset" is that I need to right-click so that I can refresh the fields; here is what I see in the designer:

[image]

Where is the dataset that will afford me a right-click action?

### UPDATE 2

When I mash Ctrl+D, it does highlight the name of the OLD stored procedure in a dropdown:

[image]

So even though I've replaced the old CommandText value (sp_ReportMonthlySales) with the new one (sp_ReportMonthlySalesEnhanced), the old one is still being referenced. How can I get it to recognize the change/the new SP data source?

### UPDATE 3

Richard Hansell's method worked. Using his method, I was able to expand "Datasets" from the ReportData pane, right-click the dataset, select Datatset Properties, and then in that dialog mash the "Refresh Fields" button. The new fields now display in the dataset's list in the Report Data pane.

If you expand your comment into an answer (you can adapt my verbiage above), I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the Dataset > Dataset Properties > Refresh fields

Comment: I can't locate the "Dataset"; please see my Update.

Comment: press CTRL+D to see it. it should appear on the left side of VS

Comment: Or if you like menus then click in the report body, then View, Report Data should include the Dataset pane.

Comment: @Aldrin: Please see Update2

Comment: @RichardHansell: Please see Update 3.

Comment: My bad, that should be Ctrl+Alt+D. Anyways, Richard already answered the another way to show up Report Data

Comment: There's always multiple ways to skin a horse ;D  I can't tell you what to do, but I would accept Aldrin's answer as it is technically correct, and the only part that was missing was how to get to the Dataset (which should be there by default anyway).  Now we have two working methods to get there, but the basic answer remains to click the Refresh Fields button.  I won't be adding a separate answer, as I don't see how this would help future people with the same question...

Comment: @RichardHansell: Yes, I did mark Buzz as the correct answerer and bountified it, thanks!